# Uknown cipher algorithm in openssl

Tags: php, docker, encryption, openssl, apple-m1

I'm getting the following error message

> unknown cipher algorithm

when trying to use the PHP function `openssl_encrypt()`. The defined cipher is "aes-128-cbc-hmac-sha256" which the whole team uses, but on my machine (with docker, macbook pro m1) this cipher doesn't appear in the array, when i run the function `openssl_get_cipher_methods()`. Is there an opportunity to add the defined cipher to my openssl config somehow?

I'm running on openssl 1.1.1n

Answer (score 3):

That is a very special purpose cipher. From the OpenSSL man page for it:

> WARNING: this is not intended for usage outside of TLS and requires calling of some undocumented ctrl functions. These ciphers do not conform to the EVP AEAD interface.

https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/EVP_aes_128_cbc_hmac_sha256.html

It is intended for use from libssl for implementing TLS and is not intended for general purpose use - unless you happen to be implementing a TLS library yourself.

Most importantly this cipher is not available on all platforms. Even when present it requires the use of undocumented ctrl functions. Unless you understand what those are and how to use them you are very likely to be using this cipher incorrectly.

> Is there an opportunity to add the defined cipher to my openssl config somehow?

No - it is not available on all platforms.

I would strongly advise against its use.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Matt. As you mentioned, it is indeed a very specific type of usecase but on the other hand it works for literally everyone else within the company but me.

Comment: Like I said it is only available on some platforms. IIRC I believe x86/x86_64 is supported. Since you have an M1 it won't be covered. Unless your company is using it for a TLS library I would strongly encourage you to get them to ditch it.

Comment: It is probably not working the way you think it is or providing the security guarantees you expect.